# Jquery, alert onclick of data by get method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think this is some kind of bug. I have no idea, because I am not much of advanced on jquery.

What I am trying to do is, do a get `request> value.html(result)>`. Once the data is shown on the page, which are some span buttons, I made a small onclick function for testing, but it is not working.

```
$('#tag').click(function(){ alert(0); }); });
```

An get request example:

```
$.get( "tags.php?page=1&cat=dogs", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

and this is what tags.php returns:

```
<span class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="tag">aaa</span><span class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="tag">bbb</span>
```

So this data is shown into the page correctly, but what I am trying to do is get the value of span. As you can see I made a simple alert function if span was clicked and it does not work. It works with other span buttons on the page, but not with this one which are displayed form get request.

Thanks for the help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click','#tag',function(){alert(0);});`. This way, the event is bound to the document, not to not-yet-existing elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Oh, and you have 2 `span` elements with the ID `#tag`. That is not valid. Use classes if you are going to have multiple elements

Comment: i changed the id to random, and still same

Comment: @blex, that does not work

Comment: In your question you posted an extra `});`, does it correspond to anything in your actual code? If not, remove it.

Comment: @blex, yeah sorry, it worked for the first element and not for others

Comment: That is because you used the same IDs. If you do `$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){alert(0);});`, you'll see it works.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot blex, it saved em hours of headaches

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("body").on("click","#tag",function(){alert(0);});});
```

Comment: same result as blex's code, it works on first span but not on others

Comment: use a class eg. ".tag", not "#tag" because you cant have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Yes, adding same id for multiple controls in not a Valid HTML, can you try with calss name as suggested by @MariusDarila

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the event *after* you place the HTML:

```
$.get("tags.php?page=1&cat=dogs", function(data) {
    $(".result").html(data);
    $(".result").find('#tag').click(function() {
        alert("Hello world!");
    });
});
```